# Javascript: "ReferenceError: icon is not defined"

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am using openlayers to add points to a map and style them with a stylefunction. This code worked one week ago and today I loaded it without any changes and got the error "ReferenceError: icon is not defined".

The function asks for an attribute of the vector and then styles it with different images, according to the attribute.

```
var styleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
    if(feature.get('class') === 'Artificial surface') {
        icon = 'icons/Artificial_surfaces.svg'
    } else if(feature.get('class') === 'Bare land') {
        icon = 'icons/Barrenlands.svg'
    } else if(feature.get('class') === 'Cultivated land') {
        icon = 'icons/Cultivated_land.svg'
    } else if(feature.get('class') === 'Forest') {
        icon = 'icons/Forests.svg'
    } else if(feature.get('class') === 'Grassland') {
        icon = 'icons/Grasslands.svg'
    } else if(feature.get('class') === 'Shrubland') {
        icon = 'icons/Shrublands.svg'
    } else if(feature.get('class') === 'Water body') {
        icon = 'icons/Waterbodies.svg'
    } else if(feature.get('class') === 'Wetland') {
        icon = 'icons/Wetland.svg'
    }
    return [new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
            src: icon,
            scale: 0.7
        })
    })]
};

var points = new ol.layer.Vector ({
    title: 'Gathered Points',
    source: vectorTwo,
    style: styleFunction
});
```

I am quite new to javascript, so probably it is a simple error I am facing, but I did not find a solution for it and I am kind of confused because it worked a week ago and I didn't apply any changes.

Comment: Declaring `icon` without the `var` keyword sets the variable as global. Is there a reason for that? If not try declaring all your `icon` declarations with the `var` keyword.

Comment: Furthermore, you should have ending semicolons `;` on each statement. `icon = 'icons/Artificial_surfaces.svg ;'`

Comment: Instead of `var` on each `icon =` line you could insert just one `var icon;` declaration before the first `if`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code needs some syntax adjustments. You are missing many semicolons `;` and your `icon` variable is declared as global. I have had trouble doing that at times and found that making it local with the `var` keyword cleaned things up. If you need to have that variable global, just declare it outside of the function without a value, then assign the value within the function. Here is my version of better syntax with your code:

```
var styleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
    var icon ;
    if(feature.get('class') === 'Artificial surface') {
        icon = 'icons/Artificial_surfaces.svg' ;
    } else if(feature.get('class') === 'Bare land') {
        icon = 'icons/Barrenlands.svg' ;
    } else if(feature.get('class') === 'Cultivated land') {
        icon = 'icons/Cultivated_land.svg' ;
    } else if(feature.get('class') === 'Forest') {
        icon = 'icons/Forests.svg' ;
    } else if(feature.get('class') === 'Grassland') {
        icon = 'icons/Grasslands.svg' ;
    } else if(feature.get('class') === 'Shrubland') {
        icon = 'icons/Shrublands.svg' ;
    } else if(feature.get('class') === 'Water body') {
        icon = 'icons/Waterbodies.svg' ;
    } else if(feature.get('class') === 'Wetland') {
        icon = 'icons/Wetland.svg' ;
    }
    return [new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
            src: icon,
            scale: 0.7
        })
    })] ;
};

var points = new ol.layer.Vector ({
    title: 'Gathered Points',
    source: vectorTwo,
    style: styleFunction
}) ;
```

Also, I highly suggest using a `switch` statement over the many `if else` statements you use. Makes for cleaner code and you only need to pass one argument. You can read about switch statements [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp). They should be fairly easy to understand.

Comment: Those semicolons you added are not required. Whether they should be used or not can be argued about, but they are not necessary.

Comment: @t.niese I know that, but some browsers may not accept their absence. Especially if you are in an strict XHTML environment. It is always good advice to use them.

Comment: @t.niese either way, my answer is aimed at the declaration of the OP's `icon` variable declaration.

Comment: In the end it was not about my syntax, it worked correctly in the way I posted it. The error was caused by geoserver. But still, thanks to your answer I see that I can improve my syntax and I also did not know about the switch statement yet. So thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have most certainly introduced a new `class` that is returned for `feature.get('class')`

You will get a `ReferenceError: icon is not defined` error if none of your conditions in `styleFunction` is true, because if that happens then `icon` will not be assigned and because you don't have a definition of `icon` anywhere the `ReferenceError` is thrown at your `new ol.style.Icon`.

To solve that problem you on the one hand have to add a definition of `icon` using `let` (or for older environment `var`) and you probably want to initialize it with a default value if none of the if blocks evaluate to true.

```
var styleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
    var icon /* = 'icons/Default.svg'  */
    if (feature.get('class') === 'Artificial surface') {
      icon = 'icons/Artificial_surfaces.svg'
    } else if (feature.get('class') === 'Bare land') {
      icon = 'icons/Barrenlands.svg'
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: This answer is basically the same as others.

Comment: Also it is bad advice not to encourage ending your statements with semicolons `;`.

Comment: @Xavier The others all miss the point why the problem suddenly appeared without any changes in the code. Because the missing definition does not necessarily result in the given error.

Comment: @Xavier There are many valid points in using semicolons and in not using them. Except some really ancient browsers (even IE 6 is able to deal with code that does not have semicolons) it does not matter, and nowadays you can choose whatever you want. There are various large projects like npm, github, mongodb, express, atom, electron, ... that use acoding style that omits semicolons.

Comment: Using semicolons is never a bad idea, and should be encouraged. Especially if you are working in XMTL, or any other strict environment..

Comment: As for the reason the error is now being thrown without changes to the shown script; there can be other reasons not mentioned. Such as another script that works with this one, that the OP has not mentioned.

Comment: Either way, what you and I both answered will give him the solution he is after.

Comment: @Xavier the answer is answered given to the information of the question. And if the code did not change and the error appreat out of sudden, then this is the only explanation, because the code did not change.

Comment: @Xavier XHTML is not relevant for the behaviour of `;`, and except if you need to maintain some legacy code you should never use XHTML. The `<!doctype html>` was always the doctype of choice because it resulted in the best browser cross browser compatibility, and was therefor adapted as html5 doctype. And even with `"use strict"` in js there is not problem with those `;`. I don't want to advocate for not using semicolons, but to say that not using them harms is plain wrong, it is a matter of personal choice and opinion.

Comment: XHTML is a W3C standard.

Comment: As I stated before, it is always a good idea to use semicolons to end your statements. You will never have to worry about it. Why add the risk?

Comment: @Xavier I didn't say anything else about XHTML. XHTML was a well meant attempt for a better HTML 4.0 which unfortunately failed. The finalization of XHTML 2.0 that was really promising was discontinued in 2009 in favor of html5 which is the current modern html standard of w3c. So there only exists XHTML 1.1 which is basicly HTML 4 in XML. That's why I sayed it should only exists in old projects because it is a discontinued standard.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it, XHTML is no longer a standard. Well I'm assuming that has a lot to do with too many lazy programmers not wanting to change their markup to meet the strict standards. I have been using it for years and will continue to use it in all my projects. But this is off topic so I will part here. Thanks for the info :)